# Oneline string comparison in sh

Tags: linux, bash, sh

What is the equivalent expression in `sh` of the following `bash` expression?

```
[ ! "${LOCAL}" == "true" ] && echo "other" || echo "local"
```

Comment: Should be `=`, not `==`.

Comment: And you want `"$LOCAL"` (Note the quotes) in case it's empty or has spaces or something.

Comment: Don't use `a && b || c` as a ternary conditional operator at all. If both `a` and `b` fail, `c` still runs. Use `if a; then b; else c; fi` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shawn's comment this is the answer on the initial question

```
[ ! "${LOCAL}" = "true" ] && echo "other" || echo "local"
```